# uploading file in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

Hi I am using paperclip in my rails application to upload files. I would like to know how to pas the original file path in a form_tag. Or get the original file path in the controller, to be specific
Thanks

```
<%= form_tag upload_categories_path, :method => :get do %>
    <td><%= file_field_tag :file_name %></td>
    <td><%= submit_tag t('submit') %></td>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: In my controller, I would like to get the file path so that I can open it to process it with roo (the file are spread sheets). So the main purpose is to get the file path for further processing and it is not attached to any model (hence the usage of form_tag)

Answer (score 1):

Modify your form tag :

```
<%= form_tag upload_categories_path, :html => { :multipart => true }, :method => :get do %>
    <td><%= file_field_tag :file_name %></td>
    <td><%= submit_tag t('submit') %></td>
<% end %>
```

In your post action, you can get the file path by:

```
params[:file_name].path
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. the params[:file_name] is a string and does not have the 'path' method

Comment: What exactly are you getting in  params[:file_name]?

Comment: The name of the file (a string)

Comment: I replaced :html => { :multipart => true } with just :multipart => true and I have the following parameters."file_name"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f1d9f892ec0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20141126-15107-1kj1i17>,
 @original_filename="categories.ods",
 @content_type="application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet",
 @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file_name\"; filename=\"categories.ods\"\r\nContent-Type: application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet\r\n">,
 "category_id"=>"5",
 "commit"=>"Submit",
 "locale"=>"en"}

Comment: How do I get the original file path from this?

Comment: Yes, it gives me /tmp/RackMultipart20141126-15107-dpkle9. But that's not the original path

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have added :html => { :multipart => true } in your Form. like

```
<%= form_tag upload_categories_path, :method => :get, :html => { :multipart => true } do %>
    <td><%= file_field_tag :file_name %></td>
    <td><%= submit_tag t('submit') %></td>
<% end %>
```

Ref [uploading file rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#uploading-files)

Comment: I replaced :html => { :multipart => true } with just :multipart => true and I have the following parameters."file_name"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f1d9f892ec0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20141126-15107-1kj1i17>, @original_filename="categories.ods", @content_type="application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file_name\"; filename=\"categories.ods\"\r\nContent-Type: application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet\r\n">, "category_id"=>"5", "commit"=>"Submit",

Comment: How do I get the original file path from these params